# How to obtain F1, precision, recall and confusion matrix

Tags: r, svm

the goal of my project is to predict the accuracy level of some textual descriptions.

I made the vectors with FASTTEXT.

TSV output:

```
 label lenght
1     0   1:43
2     0   1:10
3     0    1:8
4     0  1:110
5     1  1:105
6     0  1:446
```

Then I'm processing the .tsv files using the library e1071  by this script:

```
library (e1071)

accuracy.model = read.table(file = 'file.tsv', sep = '\t', header = FALSE, col.names= c( "label", "lenght" ))

head(accuracy.model)

classifier = svm( formula = label ~ .,
                  data = accuracy.model,
                  type = 'C-classification',
                  kernel = 'radial',
                  cost = 32,
                  gamma = 8,
                  cross  = 10)

classifier
```

Doing the cross validation (10 folds) I'm able to retrieve the overall accuracy percentage.

I would like to have also the F1 score, precision and recall value.

For the confusion matrix I went through some others stack thread and I figured out that has to be done using the caret library but I don't know how to do it.

Suggestions?

Regards

Comment: A note of caution, i noticed you have only 1 independent variable, which is really odd for using an svm.  You might wanna check whether this is sound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we fit a model like this:

```
library(caret)
library(e1071)
data=iris
data$Species = ifelse(data$Species=="versicolor","v","o")

classifier = svm( formula = Species ~ .,
                  data = data,
                  type = 'C-classification',
                  kernel = 'radial',
                  cost = 32,
                  gamma = 8,
                  cross  = 10)
```

Then we get the confusion matrix:

```
mat = table(classifier$fitted,data$Species)
```

And apply the caret function:

```
confusionMatrix(mat)$byClass

         Sensitivity          Specificity       Pos Pred Value 
           1.0000000            1.0000000            1.0000000 
      Neg Pred Value            Precision               Recall 
           1.0000000            1.0000000            1.0000000 
                  F1           Prevalence       Detection Rate 
           1.0000000            0.6666667            0.6666667 
Detection Prevalence    Balanced Accuracy 
           0.6666667            1.0000000
```

You can apply it in your case.